How many extra bits of security can I get from an intermediate finalisation of SipHash-2-4?
I'm currently using SipHash-2-4 to hash 4096-byte blocks into 64-bit hashes.  The key is secret, as that is required by SipHash.
I have 128 bits of space available for hashes, but I don't want to use the 128-bit variant of SipHash, as it is only half as fast.
(Only the original 64-bit hash will be used for the hashtable.  I would like to use the other 64-bits to reduce the probability of a collision from 1-in-2^32 to a lower value.)
If I finalised SipHash-2-4 after hashing the first 2048 bytes and then carried on hashing until the end of the 4096 bytes, I would have two 64-bit hashes at the cost of just four additional SipRounds.
(This will require me to make a version of SipHash-2-4 with a different API, as the finalisation function will need to make a copy of the state before applying the last four SipRounds.)
Obviously this is not as good as using the 128-bit SipHash.
Is there a way of reasoning how much better SipHash(msg[0..2048], key) ++ SipHash(msg[0..4096], key) is than SipHash(msg[0..4096], key)?
i.e. Is the probability of a 128-bit collision still 1-in-2^32, 1-in-2^64 or somewhere in between?  If in between, what is the chance of a 128-bit collision?
Is there a better way of utilising the extra 64-bits of hash space, with the aim of increasing collision resistance at negligible performance cost?  E.g. Eight CRC-8s?
